# How to create an extension method on a class in C#?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'd like to write an extension method for string, which appears as a static method on System.String - I've not managed to get that done.

Is that possible? If so how? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want do to that? Give us an example, and maybe we can come up with a different idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible. Extension methods let you add what look like instance methods, and not static methods.